# bootstrap icon not loading however available in node_modules

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have download npm install bootstrap-icons --save and it was downloaded successfully inside node_modules..

in the html file when i include it is not showing icon however works only when i include using hyperlink.

### Not working one

```
<link  type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

### Working one

```
<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
-->
```

### html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link  type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


<!--
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
-->


<script type="text/javascript" src="./script/jretrieve.js"> </script>


<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please mention the framework that you are using ? If it's reactJS, angular or express, I can help you out

Comment: i am using express

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

The difference is putting dot-and-slash `./` to state a relative path.

Comment: tried it i was getting this error "Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."